# Get value of attribute of an XML node (with namespaces)

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

Here's the XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<container version="1.0" xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:container">
<rootfiles>
<rootfile media-type="application/oebps-package+xml" full-path="EPUB/wasteland.opf"/>
</rootfiles>
</container>
```

And here's my code

```
      XElement XmlElement;
      XmlElement =  XElement.Load(containerXml.Stream);


      TextBlock tbl= new TextBlock();
      foreach (XElement level1Element in XmlElement.Elements("rootfiles"))
      {
          foreach (XElement level2Element in level1Element.Elements("rootfile"))
          {
              tbl.Text = level2Element.Attribute("full-path").Value;
          }
      }
```

The textblock should change to "EPUB/wasteland.opf" but why it wouldn't?

Comment: You know that you are assigning text in a loop? That means only last value will stay

Comment: I know, but there's only one value. It should be that one, isn't it?

Comment: Simply get single value with `FirstOrDefault()` of `SingleOrDefault()` method

Comment: OH It worked, thank you very much, i didn't notice the Namespace, this problem took me a day so awful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing namespace:

```
var xdoc = XDocument.Load(containerXml.Stream);
XNamespace ns = "urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:container";
var path = xdoc.Descendants(ns + "rootfile")
                .Select(r => (string)r.Attribute("full-path"))
                .FirstOrDefault();
```

And you can assign path to text block:

```
tbl.Text = path;
```